# An efficient way to implement a ecommerce Cart using Spring and MongoDb

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, lombok

I am learning Spring and I am trying to find an efficient way to implement a Cart for an ecommerce.

My requirements are that I must use MongoDb.  Also I understand that a Cart must be linked to only one User (reasonable, right?) and it encompasses a list of itens.  My difficulty is to find out the better way to do that.

My first thought was create a Cart like a relational db, but Mongo is not relational.
In a relational way I would create:

- a table for item
- a table for user;
- a table for cart with a fk to user id;
- a table for items inside the cart with a fk to item and a fk to cart id;

But I must get rid off the relational addiction when dealing with MongoDb.
So my actual attempt is:

```
package br.com.daniel.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
@Document(collection = "cartitem")
public class Cart implements Serializable, Comparable<Cart>{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4126573094618706732L;
    @Id
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @JsonProperty   
    private String id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @JsonProperty
    List<CartItem> itens;
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Cart o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The CartItem is described below.

```
package br.com.daniel.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.DBRef;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "cartitem")
public class CartItem implements Serializable, Comparable<CartItem >{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1131052187929548122L;

    @Id
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @DBRef
    private Item item;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @JsonProperty   
    private Integer quantity;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(CartItem o) {
        return o.getItem().compareTo(o.getItem());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((item == null) ? 0 : item.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((quantity == null) ? 0 : quantity.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof CartItem )) {
            return false;
        }
        CartItem other = (CartItem ) obj;
        if (item == null) {
            if (other.item != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!item.equals(other.item)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (quantidade == null) {
            if (other.quantity != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!quantidade.equals(other.quantity)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

My doubts are:

- Is this the bes tway to implement?
- Are the annotations @Document correct for the sake of my e-commerce cart project?